# React js - In react-phone-input-2 how to make country code editable false and also show placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I need to show the placeholder after country code and the code will not be editable, but its not showing, I am using react functional components.

this is my code below

```
<PhoneInput
             className="inputTextDirLeft"
             country={'us'}
             type="text"
             inputStyle={{width: '100%'}}
             countryCodeEditable={false}
             onlyCountries={formFieldData.formFlowData.countryCodes.map(function (x) {
                return x.toLowerCase()
              })}
              placeholder="5xxxxxxxx"
              onChange={(phone, data) => {
               setValue('country_code', data.countryCode.toUpperCase())
               setNumberVal(phone)
              }}
/>
```

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

To make the country code non-editable while showing a placeholder in `react-phone-input-2`, you've mostly got it right. However, ensure your `countryCodeEditable` prop is set to `false` as you've done. The placeholder showing after the country code and being uneditable should work with the `placeholder` prop as you've set it to 5xxxxxxxx. If the placeholder isn't showing as expected, double-check the `inputStyle` and other CSS that might be overriding the visibility of the placeholder. Also, ensure that `react-phone-input-2`'s version you're using supports these features as expected.